# Dealing with poisson distributions from the Cambridge Admissons Exam

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, poisson-distribution, fake-proofs

I would like to ask the (iii) part of the following question:

[image]

**My solution:**
Consier the time period of lenght $t$, starting from when they both start fishing. The probability that Adam catches one or more fishes is given by $$1-e^{\frac{-\lambda t}{T}},$$
as the number of fish cought in a time interval $T$ follows a poisson distribution. Similarly, the probability that Eve catches no fishes in the time period of $t$ is
$$e^{\frac{-\mu t}{T}}.$$
Therefore, the probability that Adam catches a fish first, in the time period $t$, is
$$e^{\frac{- \mu t}{T}}\times(1-e^{\frac{-\lambda t}{T}})$$.
We need now consider all cases, which are given by $0\leq t \leq T$, done by intigration. Therefore,
the desired probability is
$$=\int_{0}^{T} e^{\frac{- \mu t}{T}}\times(1-e^{\frac{-\lambda t}{T}}) dt=\frac{-T}{\mu}e^\mu + \frac{T}{\mu + \lambda}e^{-(\mu + \lambda)}+\frac{-T}{\mu}-\frac{T}{\lambda + \mu}.$$

However, this is wrong. According to the markscheme, one just has to note that this is the same as setting $r=1$ (in part (i)) and $k=1$ (in part (ii)). This give the answer as
$$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}.$$

**My question:**
Where have I gone wrong with my methodology?

Comment: Hint: What is the distribution of the time until Adam catches his first fish (and similarly for Eve)?